# can't get element's value

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm trying to retrieve the element's value.
Here is the HTML element.

```html
<input id="UserLoginName" type="text" readonly="readonly" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10">
```

The input contains value (I can see the value), but I can't get the text\ value no matter what I try.

```
m_mainDriver.FindElement(By.Id("UserLoginName")).Text
```

Answer (score 2):

In `<input>` tags the text is kept in the `value` attribute, even if you can't see it in the DOM, not in the `Text` property

```
m_mainDriver.FindElement(By.Id("UserLoginName")).GetAttribute("value")
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should wait until the element is fully loaded before accessing it and getting it's value attribute.
Also since this is the `input` element you should get the `value` attribute, not the text.
As following:

```
using WaitHelpers = SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers;

IWebElement webElement = wait.Until(WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("UserLoginName")));
webElement.GetAttribute("value");
```

Or more shortly

```
using WaitHelpers = SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers;

string text_val = wait.Until(WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("UserLoginName"))).GetAttribute("value");
```